# Improper Roof Valley installation?

Tags: roof

- New Build (2022)
- A month later (after move in) region received snow, low temps, and an ice dam formed at the valley and began to leak into the garage. Submitted warranty, and builder came around and supposedly fixed it. However, we also did not have any further snow in the region to test it out.
- Approaching one year warranty. Hired inspector. They looked at it and said it was not properly installed again. Said the valley shingle is on the lower slope and this is improper.

Before I go ahead and submit a request, wondering just based on first impression if it might need fixing again?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not a professional roofer, but I can tell you that the installation is wrong.
The lower roof, (in yellow)  should be run up into the steeper pitch of the gable. Then the gable shingles should be laid and terminated aprox. below the red line to make a valley .  ( admittedly my drawing is poor, and measurements are not accurate, but you get the idea.)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the slope on that whole area you've highlighted is all wrong.  It should match the rest of the roof above and below.